# Customizing filename completion in Ex-mode

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Is there a way I can customize how vim does filename completion when I'm in ex-mode (on the `:` line)?

I never want to tab-complete to some filetypes (*.o, *.hi), and I'd rather they not pop up first.

Comment: At least prioritizing the completions would be cool. It usually brings me so much frustration, when I type `:edit fooba<TAB><CR>` expecting to open `foobar.cpp` and end up opening binary ELF called `foobar`. `:/`

Comment: @ulidtko: see `suffixes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following in `$MYVIMRC`

```
set wildignore=*.o,*.hi
```

Comment: Also see the `suffixes` option, as mentioned in `:help wildignore`.